# How can I broadcast a Twilio (group room) video conference?

Tags: ffmpeg, twilio, sip, video-conferencing

I have been trying different solutions/approaches for last few days and posting here to get some more options.

I am planning to use Twilio's **Programmable Video** solution with **Group room** (*upto 50 participants*) to allow hosts/presenters to join video conference meeting. Right now I am able to setup and get started [with quickstart example here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js)

Also, in parallel, **I need to be able to broadcast that live meeting room through RTMP/HLS (audio+video)** streaming that can be viewed (through another portal) by large user set (ideally around 10k+)

Twilio support team suggested - *integrating Twilio Video with Wowza using screenscrapping and ffmpeg (i.e. render the video into a (maybe virtual) screen, capture it and send to Wowza using ffmpeg.)*

I am new to both ffmpeg and wowza. However, I am looking to see high level solution which can be used to achieve this (*with minimum hanging parts*).

**Ideal flow i can think of is**

- Start a Twilio video conference room with actual presenters
- all participants share there video and audio tracks with each other in the room - standard behavior
- a new ghost-participant joins-in from stand-alone server ([from wowza or SIP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/adding-programmable-voice-participants-video-rooms)) and subscribes to audio-video tracks in conference.
- arrange & combine those tracks into one channel and stream it as HLS
- this ghost-participant will also be able to identify dominant speaker and re-arrange video tracks to show current speaker occupying bigger space (just like zoom)
- and of course, this streamed video (with audio) will be one-way and viewers cannot interact. Just see be able to see the room broadcasting.

**Also/FYI**
I have tried exploring few more options below (with no success)

1. [a blog here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1058144/Taking-audio-stream-from-Twilio-by-SIP-and-sending) explain how can we broadcast a twilio audio
   conference. At the bottom it also mention about video streaming. but, I am not getting how can we use SIP to get video stream that can be broadcasted. Also, how can I manipulate video tracks to show dominant speakers in full screen view Vs other participant in thumbnail view i.e. custom layouts.
2. I also explored option of [Wowza WebRTC streaming](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-webrtc-with-wowza-streaming-engine) to achieve this, but it has got other technical challenges with setting up video room with multiple participants. I am going to reach out to them to see if this use-case is possible with their offering.
3. I am looking for something as [simple as here](https://docs.pexip.com/admin/streaming_wowza_cloud.htm) - dial as guest participant into video room from standalone streaming server/wowza server. And get output as single stream to broadcast.

Any other pointers or links to solutions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do something very similar, did you manage to do it? If yes, can you please share how?

Comment: Hi @Danish. I am in the middle of the same type of solution. Did you ever find a good way to achieve this?

Comment: @PepitoFernandez or Danish, did you ever get this working?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I found that Wowza can offer this capability. Unfortunately, Twilio doesn't offer anything like this, nor they have it in their plans.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of moving parts here. The article on codeproject looks interesting, but I'm not sure how the SIP "call" that also supports video (via added codec) can be used to support a ghost participant's screen. Anyone find a solution and get it working?